# JavaScript: get multiple functions to one

Tags: javascript, function, object, variables, arguments

Here is a piece of code:

```
var Whatever = function(){

     Whatever = {},
     width = 120,
     height = 80,
     ...

      Whatever.width = function (_) {

        if (!arguments.length) return width;
        width = _;
        return Whatever;

      };

      Whatever.height = function (_) {

        if (!arguments.length) return height;
        height = _;
        return Whatever;

      };

      ...

    return Whatever;

}
```

If Whatever has a few parameters, I don't mind to clone:

```
Whatever.{parameter} = function (_) {

    if (!arguments.length) return {parameter};
    {parameter} = _;
    return Whatever;

};
```

But if there're lots of them, can it be optimized to one function, which goes through every parameter?

UPDATED: Bergi has offered to use a closure-returning function. Fine.

```
var setParam(_){

if (!arguments.length) 

return {parameter};
{parameter} = _;
return Whatever;

}
```

And in this case how to pass {parameter}? In C/C++ pointers (reference address) could be used but in JavaScript?

Comment: do you have an example what you like to do with the structure? btw, `Object` is not a good target for an assignment.

Comment: What is `proportional`? Did you mean `var proportional = {}` instead of `Object = {}`?

Comment: As usual: put the repeated code in a function. In this case, a closure-returning one.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make a mockup out of a real piece of code. Updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a closure over a single variable and instantiate this combo multiple times:

```
function makeGetterSetter(value, setterResult) {
    return function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return value;
        value = _;
        return setterResult;
    };
}
```

then use

```
function Whatever() {
    const instance = {};
    instance.width = makeGetterSetter(120, instance);
    instance.height = makeGetterSetter(80, instance);
    return instance;
}
```

There's no way to achieve this but keep `width` and `height` as local variables.

Comment: Cheers! Gonna try it.